# Converting Imperative to Declarative code for nonconsecutive one implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, java-8

I want to know how to convert my nonconsecutive ones problem to declarative logic.

I've implemented and tested an imperative implementation of a function that inputs a single int parameter and return an ArrayList of strings of all binary strings that do not have consecutive 1s. I've tested it but the TC of the function makes it impractical past 15. I want to know if there is a way to use lambdas to speed things up a little. This is all under the understanding that the problem is inherently exponential and lambdas might not be the place to look. In a sense, I am just asking this question to get more comfortable with lambdas.

```
public ArrayList<String> nonconsecutiveOnes(int n){

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < (int)Math.pow(2,n); i++ ){
            String a= Integer.toBinaryString(i); 
            if (a.contains("11")){
                continue;
            }
            if (a.length() < n)
            {
                char[] c = new char[n- a.length()];

                Arrays.fill(c, '0');
                String zeros = new String(c);

                a = zeros + a;
            }
                results.add(a);
        }
            return results; 
     }     
}
```

I've already tested it. Haven't tried edge cases, though. Still need it to only return null if under a length of 1.

Comment: I'm actually OK with it taking 0. I just need to catch negative int exceptions. That's the big caveat here.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are asked to output binary representation of all numbers lower than 2^n that does not contain 2 consecutive 1's.
You may rephrase it as all strings of 1's and 0's of length n, with no "11" in it.

Than you basically may look at that as a tree, where you output it symbol by symbol, where you branch after 0 (to try 0 and 1), but do not branch after 1.

Not sure lambdas as in java lambdas help in speeding this up.

But you might consider trying to solve this recursively, that should land you in the vicinity of functional implementation.

For example (no claims for it to be optimal):

```
public class Ex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printAllStrings(3);
    }

    public static void printAllStrings(int length) {
        printAllStrings("0", length);
        printAllStrings("1", length);
    }

    public static void printAllStrings(String prefix, int length) {
        if (prefix.length() == length) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } else {
            printAllStrings(prefix + "0", length);
            if (prefix.endsWith("0")) {
                printAllStrings(prefix + "1", length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One use of java lambdas would be to pass a Consumer and feed Strings to it, instead of stdout'ing them. )

Comment: Great answer! Note that it improves drastically on the time complexity by baking in the logic that trivially skips anything with consecutive ones.